# ASP redirect with delay

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
if (user.EmailConfirmationCode == confcode) {
  user.EmailConfirmed = true;
  _context.Update(user);
  _context.SaveChanges();
}
else {
  ViewData["Message"] = "Onay kodu hatalı. Kontrol edip tekrar deneyiniz!";
  return Redirect("/onepoint/Login/MailConfirm");
}
```

I need to go back to `MailConfirm` with 3 or 4 seconds delay so people can read the message . Above code is in my `Controller.cs`.

Comment: Either return a view to display to the user, or redirect the user to another action which returns a view.  You can't do both in the same operation.  Which do you want to do?

Comment: I want user go back to Form again and fill the confirm code again

Comment: Define "go back to Form again".  What should this controller action do?  Should it render a view to the user?  If so, you're looking for `return View();`.  It's not really clear what the problem is, either return a view or return a redirect, one or the other, whichever you want.

Comment: What you want is unclear but it's certainly not going to happen with that code. A *view* is rendered only after an action returns. That means the string stored inside `ViewData` will never appear to the user until the method returns. When an action returns, the ASP.NET runtime will take its result and execute the View code using the data returned by the action. The generated HTML will be sent to the browser.

Comment: I have two input. One for confirm code that goes to email the user who wants to signup and the other input is email when user fill both inputs then clicks the button and than code block starts for confirm the code in the input and the mail code if code not match then this message block will run for 5 seconds and after user saw this message page will go back to 2 input again

Comment: If you want to display a notification, toast, modal or alert to the user, add the proper code to your view and display the element you want when the `message` has a value. It's a lot easier to do that if you use a proper model instead of ViewData because you can bind eg a toast's value and display attributes to model properties directly. Using eg Boostrap's [Toast](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/) you can show or hide the message by changing the toast's class. The delay will be set in your JS/HTML code, not the server code, in this case through the `data-bs-delay` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay and redirect would probably best be done on the client side.

Example function in Javascript:

```
function redirectAfterTimeout(){
   setTimeout('Redirect()', 4000);
}
function Redirect() 
{  
    window.location="/onepoint/Login/MailConfirm"; 
}
```

You could then add a javascript function to the view using a viewbag.

View code:

```
@if (ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction)
        </script>
    }
```

Controller code:

```
if (user.EmailConfirmationCode == confcode) {
  user.EmailConfirmed = true;
  _context.Update(user);
  _context.SaveChanges();
}
else {
  ViewData["Message"] = "Onay kodu hatalı. Kontrol edip tekrar deneyiniz!";
  ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = "redirectAfterTimeout();";
}
```